# Android support screen sizes in inches

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I'm building an android app that runs on an Android device one of the requirements to support screen sizes 5”, 7” and 10”. I didn't find how to provide multi screen support.

How can I support screen sizes 5”, 7” and 10” for different devices in my project.

Comment: Is it this you mean? https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks any research effort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant `supporting multiple screen`. First of all we can’t use fixed dimension in our components. For example we can’t specify a component with using 60px. Instead using `px` we can use `dp`.
Dp is a `density independent pixel` that is used in Android to specify dimensions in a “virual” manner. It is the SO that will adapt our virtual dimension to the real one using the real screen density.